# Issue with AutoComplete of jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, json

Am using jQuery 1.9.1. Facing a issue in autocomplete. Am populating the autocomplete values in JSON ajax call. When i try with the autocomplete event, it is not working and giving some strange reponse. After getting the values from JSON call. autocomplete is populating the values only after two alerts. In both the alerts am checking the vaues i got from JSON call. In my first alert, values are empty but in the second call values are present. in case if am not putiing the alerts. an extra html ajax call is getting submitting in the name of screenload action. this i could see in firefox firebug. Attached the code and screenshot(refer for case 2: incase of no alerts)

```
var airports = "";
$.ajax({
url: "populateAirportCodes?fragments="+element.target,
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(org),
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) {                             
airports = data;   
}
});
$(".origincode").autocomplete({                                     
source: airports                                                                        
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing `airports` as the `source` before your ajax request has returned and assigned it. Put your autocomplete code inside of the ajax success function

Comment: Check this [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). Check the view source.

Comment: Should `data` in the object of the `$.ajax()`-argument really be a *stringified* JSON? To my knowledge it should be "either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}", see [jQuery-doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: may be, you need put **`async: false`** as an ajax property

Comment: It worked from your suggestions. to summarize from above suggestions .. Moved the autocomplete inside callback function and made the ajax call with async:false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var airports = "";
$.ajax({
url: "populateAirportCodes?fragments="+element.target,
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(org),
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) {                             
$(".origincode").autocomplete({                                     
source: data ,
minLength: 1,

});  

}
});
```

Comment: It worked. but not fully. in the u mentioned, autocomplete is not working on first key press. It is idle on first keypress. on the nextpress it is populating.

Comment: But i need to populate the values when user starts typring from the first word.

Comment: It worked from your suggestions. to summarize from above suggestions .. Moved the autocomplete inside callback function and made the ajax call with async:false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var airports = "";

$(".origincode").autocomplete({                                     
  source:"populateAirportCodes?fragments="+element.target,                                                               
});
```

The response to be in this format

```
  [{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
   }];
```